# Registration fail error in sipdemo application

Tags: android, sip

I am using SIPDEMO application . when i am login by username , domain, and password . it give me "Registration fail error" .. 
 I have checked in my iphone and working well . so there is not any problem in my sip accounts.

i have also read the completed code but unable to find any error

please expert help me

this is code:-

```
public class WalkieTalkieActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {

public String sipAddress = null;

public SipManager manager = null;
public SipProfile me = null;
public SipAudioCall call = null;
public IncomingCallReceiver callReceiver;

private static final int CALL_ADDRESS = 1;
private static final int SET_AUTH_INFO = 2;
private static final int UPDATE_SETTINGS_DIALOG = 3;
private static final int HANG_UP = 4;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.walkietalkie);

    ToggleButton pushToTalkButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.pushToTalk);
    pushToTalkButton.setOnTouchListener(this);

    // Set up the intent filter.  This will be used to fire an
    // IncomingCallReceiver when someone calls the SIP address used by this
    // application.
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL");
    callReceiver = new IncomingCallReceiver();
    this.registerReceiver(callReceiver, filter);

    // "Push to talk" can be a serious pain when the screen keeps turning off.
    // Let's prevent that.
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    initializeManager();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // When we get back from the preference setting Activity, assume
    // settings have changed, and re-login with new auth info.
    initializeManager();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (call != null) {
        call.close();
    }

    closeLocalProfile();

    if (callReceiver != null) {
        this.unregisterReceiver(callReceiver);
    }
}

public void initializeManager() {
    if(manager == null) {
      manager = SipManager.newInstance(this);

      Log.v("sip_test", "manager: " + manager.toString());
    Log.v("sip_test", "isApiSupported: " + new Boolean(SipManager.isApiSupported(this)).toString());
    Log.v("sip_test", "isSipWifiOnly: " + new Boolean(SipManager.isSipWifiOnly(this)).toString());
    Log.v("sip_test", "isVoipSupported: " + new Boolean(SipManager.isVoipSupported(this)).toString());

    }

    initializeLocalProfile();
}

/**
 * Logs you into your SIP provider, registering this device as the location to
 * send SIP calls to for your SIP address.
 */
public void initializeLocalProfile() {
    if (manager == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (me != null) {
        closeLocalProfile();
    }

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    String username = prefs.getString("namePref", "");
    String domain = prefs.getString("domainPref", "");
    String password = prefs.getString("passPref", "");

    System.out.println("username " +username);
    System.out.println("domain " +domain);
    System.out.println("password " +password);

    if (username.length() == 0 || domain.length() == 0 || password.length() == 0) {
        showDialog(UPDATE_SETTINGS_DIALOG);
        return;
    }

    try {
        SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username, domain);
        builder.setPassword(password);
        me = builder.build();

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction("android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL");
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
        manager.open(me, pi, null);


        // This listener must be added AFTER manager.open is called,
        // Otherwise the methods aren't guaranteed to fire.

        manager.setRegistrationListener(me.getUriString(), new SipRegistrationListener() {
                public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {
                    updateStatus("Registering with SIP Server...");
                }

                public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {
                    updateStatus("Ready");
                }

                public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode,
                        String errorMessage) {
                    updateStatus("Registration failed.  Please check settings.");
                    System.out.println("local profile uri " + localProfileUri);
                    System.out.println("error code" + errorCode);
                    System.out.println("error message " +errorMessage);
                }
            });
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        updateStatus("Connection Error.");
        System.out.println("parse exception"+pe.getMessage());
    } catch (SipException se) {
        updateStatus("Connection error.");
        System.out.println("Connection exception"+se.getMessage());
    }
}

/**
 * Closes out your local profile, freeing associated objects into memory
 * and unregistering your device from the server.
 */
public void closeLocalProfile() {
    if (manager == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        if (me != null) {
            manager.close(me.getUriString());
        }
    } catch (Exception ee) {
        Log.d("WalkieTalkieActivity/onDestroy", "Failed to close local profile.", ee);
    }
}

/**
 * Make an outgoing call.
 */
public void initiateCall() {

    updateStatus(sipAddress);



    try {
        SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {
            // Much of the client's interaction with the SIP Stack will
            // happen via listeners.  Even making an outgoing call, don't
            // forget to set up a listener to set things up once the call is established.
            @Override
            public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
                call.startAudio();
                call.setSpeakerMode(true);
                call.toggleMute();
                updateStatus(call);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
                updateStatus("Ready.");
            }
        };

        call = manager.makeAudioCall(me.getUriString(), sipAddress, listener, 30);

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("WalkieTalkieActivity/InitiateCall", "Error when trying to close manager.", e);
        if (me != null) {
            try {
                manager.close(me.getUriString());
            } catch (Exception ee) {
                Log.i("WalkieTalkieActivity/InitiateCall",
                        "Error when trying to close manager.", ee);
                ee.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (call != null) {
            call.close();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Updates the status box at the top of the UI with a messege of your choice.
 * @param status The String to display in the status box.
 */
public void updateStatus(final String status) {
    // Be a good citizen.  Make sure UI changes fire on the UI thread.
    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            TextView labelView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sipLabel);
            labelView.setText(status);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Updates the status box with the SIP address of the current call.
 * @param call The current, active call.
 */
public void updateStatus(SipAudioCall call) {
    String useName = call.getPeerProfile().getDisplayName();
    if(useName == null) {
      useName = call.getPeerProfile().getUserName();
    }
    updateStatus(useName + "@" + call.getPeerProfile().getSipDomain());
}

/**
 * Updates whether or not the user's voice is muted, depending on whether the button is pressed.
 * @param v The View where the touch event is being fired.
 * @param event The motion to act on.
 * @return boolean Returns false to indicate that the parent view should handle the touch event
 * as it normally would.
 */
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (call == null) {
        return false;
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && call != null && call.isMuted()) {
        call.toggleMute();
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && !call.isMuted()) {
        call.toggleMute();
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0, CALL_ADDRESS, 0, "Call someone");
    menu.add(0, SET_AUTH_INFO, 0, "Edit your SIP Info.");
    menu.add(0, HANG_UP, 0, "End Current Call.");

    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case CALL_ADDRESS:
            showDialog(CALL_ADDRESS);
            break;
        case SET_AUTH_INFO:
            updatePreferences();
            break;
        case HANG_UP:
            if(call != null) {
                try {
                  call.endCall();
                } catch (SipException se) {
                    Log.d("WalkieTalkieActivity/onOptionsItemSelected",
                            "Error ending call.", se);
                }
                call.close();
            }
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case CALL_ADDRESS:

            LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            final View textBoxView = factory.inflate(R.layout.call_address_dialog, null);
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Call Someone.")
                    .setView(textBoxView)
                    .setPositiveButton(
                            android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                    EditText textField = (EditText)
                                            (textBoxView.findViewById(R.id.calladdress_edit));
                                //   sipAddress = textField.getText().toString();
                                    sipAddress= "sip:kukukkk@ekiga.net";
                                    initiateCall();

                                }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(
                            android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                    // Noop.
                                }
                    })
                    .create();

        case UPDATE_SETTINGS_DIALOG:
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setMessage("Please update your SIP Account Settings.")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            updatePreferences();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(
                            android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                    // Noop.
                                }
                    })
                    .create();
    }
    return null;
}

public void updatePreferences() {
    Intent settingsActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
            SipSettings.class);
    startActivity(settingsActivity);
}
```

}

Comment: As you can Imagine, there are thousands of possible reasons for that. You need to show some code, or better, the error trace.

Comment: bro i am facing the same prob like you.. can u help me please if u found the solution.. its very urgent.. please help me i will be very thankful to you...

Comment: @MindBlowing for actual result use to Real Android device not emulator. If you want to make sip application so use to SipDroid library. sip demo will be not good way for developing real sip application.

Comment: bro i am using real android device. an android phone but it still not working :( @RahulRawat

Comment: there may be number of resone. please leave your complete code.

Comment: @RahulRawat did u got any solution??

Comment: @AbhijitChakra SIP demo is not good if you want to development real time application. I got may of issues. Finally i moved to "IMS Droid" library. If you have solid knowledge about c. you can use "pjsip".

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your android phone is Sip supported or not.
2. Confirm this code is included in Manifest file:

   `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />`